# [GDAL][Android] how to set GDAL_DATA directory path?

Tags: android, gdal

We are  trying to use GDAL on android but we have an issue, when we want to use SpatialRference's ImportFromEPSG function (error 6).
We think we have this error because our GDAL_DATA dir set with

> gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA",dir.getAbsolutePath()) is not found,
>   or SetConfigOption ignored

but we don't know why. Directory is tested before and exists.

This is our code :

```
File file = getGCSFile();

if (file.exists())
    Log.d("GDAL", "CSV found !!!");

File dir = getGDALDataFile();

if (dir.exists())
    Log.d("GDAL", "GDAL_DATA dir found !!!");

File log = new File(dir,"log");

gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", dir.getAbsolutePath());
gdal.SetConfigOption("CPL_LOG", log.getAbsolutePath());
gdal.SetConfigOption("CPL_DEBUG", "ON");
gdal.SetConfigOption("CPL_LOG_ERRORS", "ON");
gdal.SetConfigOption("CPL_TIMESTAMP ", "ON");
gdal.SetErrorHandler("CPLLoggingErrorHandler");

gdal.AllRegister();
ogr.RegisterAll();

SpatialReference src = new SpatialReference();
SpatialReference tgt = new SpatialReference();

osr.DontUseExceptions();

//WGS 84
int error = src.ImportFromEPSG(4326);
Log.d("GDAL","error " + error);
```

would anyone have any idea to help us configure this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `dir.getAbsolutePath()`? Anyway refer this thread https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-May/036150.html

Comment: Another ref: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Building-GDAL-with-PROJ4-on-Android-td5373620.html

Comment: the output of dir.getAbsolutePath() is /data/user/0/com.gdal.test/files/gdal/data. this is a directory with read/write access for my app. i have read the first thread, but i don't understand the answer : "Linking against the libgdal.so library resolved the issue."

Answer (score 1):

GDAL Android user here, in my experience, I had to set the `PROJ_LIB` environment variable (or `SetConfigOption`) as well. The folder to use for this variable is the one that contains the `proj.db` file